# FFMPEG: How to extract a PNG sequence from a video, remove duplicate frames in the process and keep the original frame number?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a recording of an old game which has variable framerate. Since I want to process individual frames to upscale and modernize the footage I would like to avoid any duplicate frames. I know that I can use this function to extract all frames from a video:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -r 60/1 out%04d.png
```

And I know that I can remove duplicate frames using this function:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -vf mpdecimate,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB output.mov
```

However, the above command removes duplicate frames and puts frames next to each other whereas in order to keep a timecode of sorts it would be a lot more useful to be able to extract PNGs with frame number (video is progressive 60fps) but without all of the duplicates.

So, the question is: what if I want to extract PNG files BUT maintain the original corresponding framenumber within the sequence? So, if we have a video with 10 frames and frames 2-8 are duplicates it spits out 1.png 2.png 9.png and 10.png? How do I combine both bits of code listed above?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
ffmpeg -i fulltest.mov -vsync 0 -frame_pts true -vf mpdecimate out%04d.png
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.